# No errors, yet MessageService won't display anything

Tags: angular, message, primeng

I followed the documentation as per official site (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/messages) to use the MessageService yet after compiling I get no errors and no messages.

Tried the same code on different components, nothing worked.

component.ts:

```
import { MessageService } from "primeng/api";

constructor(private messageService : MessageService, ... 


showViaService() {
this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Service Message', detail:'Via MessageService'});
```

}

component.html

```
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="showViaService()">Test Message Service</button>
```

angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" ...
```

app.module.ts

```
 import {MessageService} from 'primeng/api';
 import {ToastModule} from 'primeng/toast';

 imports: [ToastModule, 


 providers: [MessageService]
```

No errors, nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I realised I didn't indicate anywhere on my html where to show the toast message...

After inserting p-toast

```
<p-toast position="top-right"></p-toast>
```

to my app.component.html it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget this at the top of the component:-

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-component.scss'],
  providers: [MessageService]
})
```

Comment: Interesting, for me it was the other way round. After I removed the provider line, it worked. Using PrimeNG 14.